# Redirect subdomain from external server to EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have two servers:

- **Server A:** my main server that reports to my *domain.com*;
- **Server B:** a EC2 server that reports via DNS IPv4 public domain from AWS (eg. *ec2-00-000-000-000.compute-0.amazonaws.com/*).

The **Server B** contains a Node server that reponds via port 8000, and works fine when I call via DNS IPv4 or public IPv4 directly.

I need create a new subdomain on Server A that will points this Server B Node instance (eg. *subdomain.domain.com*). I have done that via WHM, so I added a new DNS entry with CNAME type.

It seems to works, initially, because MXTools reports correctly my server when requested:

- **mx:subdomain.domain.com**

  ```
  +-------+----------------------+--------------------------------------------+------+
  | Type  |     Domain Name      |               Canonical Name               | ...  |
  +-------+----------------------+--------------------------------------------+------+
  | CNAME | subdomain.domain.com | ec2-00-000-000-000.compute-0.amazonaws.com | ...  |
  +-------+----------------------+--------------------------------------------+------+
  ```

But when I try to access it like: http://subdomain.domain.com:8000/ it responds with *DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN*. ICMP too don't works for *subdomain.domain.com*, but works directly on IPv4 or EC2 DNS IPv4.

On the Security Group for this instance I have enabled Inbound for:

- SSH for all;
- TCP custom 8000 for all;
- ICMP for all;

All works directly with the EC2 IP, but none via subdomain.

So I suspects that the Node server, or Amazon Linux have some firewalls that blocks it, but I have no clue for where I should search by it.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I was going to delete this post, but I will leave what happened to keep it registered for whoever needs it.

Basically, there is a waiting time for the settings to be applied, which is the **propagation time**. I already knew about that time, and I waited about 30 minutes during the tests, but it seems that it took a little more time (normally in 5 minutes I already had the right answer). Now it's working automagically!